# How to specify index of parent in xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

The following xpath `//div[contains(@text, "1")]/..` returns more than one parent for multiple object with text containing "1".

I want to get only the first parent that matches the criteria.

`//div[contains(@text, "1")]/..[1]` does not work, neither does `//div[contains(@text, "1")][1]/..`.

Any ideas on how to specify index with found parents within xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for any element with direct child with "1" text and use `@itemscope` to limit the results to the first occurrence

```
//*[div[contains(text(), "1")]][@itemscope]
```

Comment: Thanks - but i didn't need to add [@itemscope] -- '//*[div[contains(text(), "1")]][1]' and '//*[div[contains(text(), "1")]]' works

Answer (score 1):

In XPath, `//x[1]` selects every `x` that is the first child of its parent, while `(//x)[1]` selects the first `x` element in the document.

So you need

```
(//div[contains(@text, "1")])[1]
```